# How can i proper set link to react icon using React styled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, styled-components

I'd like set link for my **Facebook** and **Instagram** **React** **icons**. I have simply this code which is imporant for this question. For links inside the project i used **React Router Dom** but i've never needed link something outsite. How can i proper do it please? I tried something like `<FacebookIcon to = "" />` and `<FacebookIcon href = "" />` but nothing happened.

index.js

```
<SocialWrapper>
 <FacebookIcon/>
 <InstagramIcon/>
</SocialWrapper>
```

styles.js

```
export const SocialWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
`

export const FacebookIcon = styled(FaFacebookF)`
  color: ${white};
  font-size: 2.3rem;
  
  &:hover{
    color: ${red}
  }
`

export const InstagramIcon = styled(FaInstagram)`
  color: ${white};
  font-size: 2.3rem;
    &:hover{
        color: ${red}
    }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just put in the style or css this property

```
background-image: url()
```

Where you pass a string of a file directory or a web address

Comment: Some how its not working. I forget one important thing.. I have more Facebooks and Instagram icons :/

Comment: href won't work
To put an image, you need to use the img tag and use the src attribute. That's the only possible way

Answer (score 0):

Your going to want to wrap the Styled icon in an anchor tag with a href to your profiles. You wouldn't be able to use React Router Link to go to an external page as you have already seen and you wouldn't want to just throw a href or a button event onto an icon. Something like this should be what your after:

```
<a href="https://facebook.com/ProfileName">
  <StyledIcon />
</a>
```

MDN Anchor element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: Ou nice! Maybe just question. Is this standart way how get link for.. in this case icon?

Comment: yes anchor tags are semantically correct if you are trying to send a person from one place to another, otherwise if you where opening a modal that should be done by a button. You shouldn't try to make other elements act as links or buttons as those elements have special meaning for things like screen readers and other assistive technology.